# Why Netbeans asking login password?

Tags: netbeans, ide

Can't understand why my Netbeans(Linux) asking login and password for something every 10-30 seconds. I don't know what login and for what thing. Im not using git/svn/mercurial. Simple local new project.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean it's asking you to set a master password?  If so, this is indicative that Netbeans is unable to communicate with the operating system's native keyring.  You can [see what the problem is or disable that message entirely](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqMasterPasswordDialog), if so.